# Explicit type conversion in c language

Tags: c

if my c code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
       putchar(c);
    }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I want to know whether **int c** woud be converted into **char** , or the input character would be converted into **int** and then be stored in c.

Comment: `int` is used as the return type from `getchar` because it's wider than `char` which means it can store meta-values like `EOF` (often defined as `-1` (thus impossible to represent with `char`), which obviates the need for a side-channel. Similarly `putchar` does not use `char` as an argument (but `int`). There is no implicit nor explicit conversion from `int` to `char` in your program.

Comment: A signed `char` can represent -1, which is why `getchar` performs two conversions on the character read: first to `unsigned char` and then to `int` (with `EOF` outside the range of `unsigned char`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getchar` returns an `int` and `putchar` expects an `int` so there is no need of conversion. `char` in name may be confusing for you. But type `int` also allows to accommodate some special values for ex: `EOF`

Answer (score 5):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) of `getchar()`

```
int getchar(void);
```

So, why'd think of conversion, anyway? The return type of `getchar()` is `int`, being stored into an `int` variable.

Same goes for [`putchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar) also.

```
int putchar(int c);
```

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `getchar` is `int`, so no type conversion takes place in the assignment.